# How can I refresh the Apple mobile web app status bar style meta tag?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

My goal is to allow a user to change between dark mode and light mode. When they make a selection, I want to change the meta tag from `default` to `black` or vice versa.

Currently, I have server-side code that renders the `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` meta tag based on the user's preference of dark mode or light mode. When the user changes the mode, a form is submitted and the page refreshes with the new styles regardless because I render the applied class names on the server. For example in light mode, I might have something like this.

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" id="status-bar-style">
...
<div class="bg-blue-light"></div>
```

while in dark mode the server will return something like this.

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" id="status-bar-style">
...
<div class="bg-blue-dark"></div>
```

The problem arises when the user is in the standalone web app. The meta tag appears to be cached. No matter what I do, the status bar will not change unless the user re-downloads the web app. I have tried using javascript to replace the meta tag and reload the page, but that didn't work either.

So how can I dynamically change the `apple-mobile-web-spp-status-bar-style` meta tag while inside the web app?

Comment: How you implement your style changing? Do you upload new css file or what?

Comment: I change the names of the applied classes on the server side. So I might have something like `bg-blue-light` on light mode and `bg-blue-dark` on dark mode.

Comment: Have you tried changing the element's attribute using JavaScript?

Comment: I have tried to change the content attribute with a setTimeout, but it didn't work.

Comment: I suspect that you read your metatag at some point in your js in order to detect what theme user has. But when you update your metatag you don't trigger that piece of code that responsible for that

Comment: I forgot to mention, the class names are changed on the server. I do not use javascript to change or detect the style.

Comment: Yeah, so the page itself is certainly not cached, otherwise your dark theme would not show up at all. It must be an implementation detail from Apple that caches this specific property for the site.

Comment: I also cannot find any documentation on changing this programmatically so I am assuming that it's not possible to do so at this time.

Comment: This appears to be the case. I wrote some javascript to alert the value in the meta tag. The meta tag content appears to change even in the web app. So as expected, Apple is caching the status bar color. Surely there is some way to clear the cache of the entire web app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that'll work programmably, however you can set the status bar to translucent

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

And specify a theme color which you can change automatically, tested and works on iphone6s safari

```
 <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffd5f5">
```

And automatically change the theme color using javascript

```
function changeThemeColor(color) {
    let currentTheme = $('body').hasClass('theme-light') ? 'light' : 'dark';
    let metaThemeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");  
    if(currentTheme === 'light'){
        metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content",color);                    
    }
    else{
        metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content","#21252a");
    }                       

}
// Can be called on button click and/or page load,
```